# Error reading a JSON file into Pandas

Tags: json, pandas, import

I am trying to read a JSON file into Pandas. It's a relatively large file (41k records) mostly text.

```
{"sanders": [{"date": "February 8, 2016 Monday", "source": "Federal News           
Service", "subsource": "MSNBC \"MSNBC Live\" Interview with Sen. Bernie 
Sanders (I-VT), Democratic", "quotes": ["Well, it's not very progressive to     
take millions of dollars from Wall Street as well.", "That's a very good 
question, and I wish I could give her a definitive answer. QUOTE SHORTENED FOR 
SPACE"]}, {"date": "February 7, 2016 Sunday", "source": "CBS News Transcripts", "subsource": "SHOW: CBS FACE THE NATION 10:30 AM EST", "quotes": 
["Well, John -- John, I think that`s a media narrative that goes around and 
around and around. I don`t accept that media narrative.", "Well, that`s what  
she said about Barack Obama in 2008. "]},
```

I tried:

```
quotes = pd.read_json("/quotes.json")
```

I expected it to read in cleanly because it was file created in python. However, I got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-c1acfdf0dbc6> in <module>()
----> 1 quotes = pd.read_json("/Users/kate/Documents/99Antennas/Client\    
Files/Fusion/data/quotes.json")

/Users/kate/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in   
read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, 
keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit)
    208         obj = FrameParser(json, orient, dtype, convert_axes, 
convert_dates,
    209                           keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float,
--> 210                           date_unit).parse()
    211 
    212     if typ == 'series' or obj is None:

/Users/kate/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in parse(self)
    276 
    277         else:
--> 278             self._parse_no_numpy()
    279 
    280         if self.obj is None:

/Users/kate/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in _   
parse_no_numpy(self)
    493         if orient == "columns":
    494             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 495                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float),   
dtype=None)
    496         elif orient == "split":
    497             decoded = dict((str(k), v)

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

After reading the documentation and stackoverflow, I also tried adding `convert_dates=False` to the parameters, but that did not correct the problem. I would welcome suggestions as to how to handle this error.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the forward slash in the filename. If you run this python code from the same directory where the file is sitting, it should work.

```
quotes = pd.read_json("quotes.json")
```

Comment: tks SPKoder, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. The path is correct, and moving them into the same directory doesn't resolve this error. It seems to be a parsing issue with the date field. Some dates are not compliant. However, I need to get the data read in to clean it.

Comment: Kate Stohr - please provide a sample of the data with non-compliant date fields so that we can reproduce your problem. The sample data in the question loads without error. Also, what format do expect the result to be in? In the example you provided, I don't think Pandas would even attempt parsing dates. "Sanders" would be a column label and each entry in the associated list would be a row. Each cell contains a string with date, source, subsource, and quotes...

Comment: Tks SPKoder... I ended up getting a csv version and was able to strip the non-compliant dates. Not a great solution, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SPKoder mentioned the forward slash.  I was looking for an answer when I realized I hadn't added a / when combing filename and path (i.e. c:/path/herefile.json, instead of c:/path/here/file.json).   Anyways the error I received was ...

```
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Not a very intuitive error message, but that is what causes it.

Comment: Same issue here, somehow PyCharm (IDE) thought I wanted the data directory as the working directory. Obviously a relative path then fails...